# Javascript Number Formatting With Commas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to format numbers so they have commas between every 3 numbers. It is very glitchy however and doesn't work once it gets to 8 numbers. I've put all the code in a jsfiddle below:

```
function commaSeparateNumber(val){
    val = val.replace(',', '');
    var array = val.split('');
    var index = -3;
    while (array.length + index > 0) {
        array.splice(index, 0, ',');
        // Decrement by 4 since we just added another unit to the array.
        index -= 4;
    }
    return array.join('');
};    

$(document).on('keyup', '.test', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    value = commaSeparateNumber(value);
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R8JrF/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Woah! Did you press `Home`, `Del` keys and check how it becomes?

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick Thanks, yeah I've already seen that one and I've tried that code but I still get a similar glitch.

Comment: You should not try to format the input while it is inputted. It leads to wrong intermediate results, and to very quirky UX.

Comment: @MrGrinst Issue to be taken in a slightly tricky way. Check out my answer, posting an explanation.

Comment: Okay should I just update it with a on('change') instead?

Comment: The reason why it didn't work was, once you make changes, you need to remove all the commas, and do the formatting again, which was not done in the OP's code as well as the other answer code.

Comment: `onChange()` would really be your best option, UX wise.

Comment: Okay guys, `onChange()` and `onKeyUp()` does the same thing here. :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar No it doesn't. onChange triggers only when the field loses focus.

Comment: @MrGrinst Is the solution working?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I **improvised** the answer in the comment. What you would need is the below code only. Check this out and also the fiddle:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.test', function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/R8JrF/1/

The reason why it didn't work was, once you make changes, you need to remove all the commas, and do the formatting again, which was not done in the OP's code as well as the other answer code.

Comment: Erk! Now I can't use my arrow keys to move the cursor to the left!

Comment: What? Wait. Lemme check and return a better one. :P

Comment: @Gareth Check the original code. It is way worse. It keeps on adding commas. :) Mine's better. Will try to fix. :)

Comment: Oh your first attempt performs better than the original, but I would agree with @Bergi that this kind of formatting is not useful inside the input. You won't find a keyup solution that lets me change or add a digit in the middle of the string (and still keeps my cursor in the same place) without a lot of additional Javascript, or as I would call it "overkill"

Comment: @Gareth Lemme say you a simple one. This issue can be tackled using `onBlur()` so that, this changing gets triggered only when the field loses focus. Does it solve?

Comment: Yes, if you're happy that editing that "onblur" field can leave it temporarily looking like `1,234,55567,890`. I don't know the reason for the OP wanting commas in his input but personally I can't see the benefits, which makes it hard to know how much effort is "too much" to get it working

Comment: Yes. I understand. But when will `1,234,55567,890` - THIS come? 55567??? Say it is a typo!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31141/discussion-between-gareth-and-praveen-kumar)

Comment: when ading point for floating eg: 1,000,000.00 after this number if you add more digits the poing will replace the comma and the number will be 1,000,000.000.000

Answer (score 15):

Use `Number.prototype.toLocaleString();` [check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```
var no = 3456;
no.toLocaleString();
```

Gives 3,456

Answer (score 7):

Try [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) instead

```
var number = 1000000;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat().format(number));
// 1,000,000
```

Solution of your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/mf2s48jo/

Comment: This is a JS built-in and gets the job done perfectly. This is probably the best answer now, imo. Thanks @Taron.

Comment: @nonbeing Thank you :) Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that when you get to the 8th digit, the intermediate result has already two commas in it. Yet,

```
val = val.replace(',', '');
```

does only replace the first one. You would need to provide a regular expression with the [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) flag set:

```
val = val.replace(/,/g, '');
```

[Updated, working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R8JrF/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old question.  However, I wanted to keep my cursor at the same position within the number even while the text was getting longer or shorter depending on the number of commas being added or removed.  In the end this is what I used.  Now, if I put my cursor anywhere within my input field and change it, it will not move my cursor to the end of the number or jump around within the number.

```
jQuery(document).on('keyup', '.number-format', function(_e) {
    var _x = jQuery(this).val();
    var _cursor = _e.target.selectionStart;
    
    var _length = _x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").length;
    var _commas = _x.length - _length;
    
    jQuery(this).val(_x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","));
    
    var _newLength = _x.toString().replace(/,/g, "").length;
    var _newCommas = jQuery(this).val().length - _newLength - _commas;
    
    if (_newLength == _length && _newCommas == 0) {
        _e.target.setSelectionRange(_cursor, _cursor);
    }else{
        _e.target.setSelectionRange(_cursor - (_newLength - _length) + _newCommas, _cursor - (_newLength - _length) + _newCommas);
    }
});
```